# Why is char_length the same for every value?

Tags: postgresql, blackboard

I am trying to count the number of characters in a string, but every value I return is '100'.  The values are discussion question responses in Blackboard.  Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT char_length(dse.event_text)
FROM discussion_stream_event dse
```

This returns a '100' for every line even though the responses can range from a dozen characters to more than a thousand.  The data type for dse.event_text is character varying, but even when I cast it as text the value returned is still 100.

Any ideas how I might count these characters?  Thank you!

Comment: Unless you have some whitespace that pads these things to 100 characters (and that whitespace isn't a trailing space character which a varchar would automatically ignore upon insertion) then I can't imagine what the issue would be. Do you get different results when using function `length()`?

Comment: same result actually

Comment: Sounds like your column event_text is defined al `char(100)`; Try running: `SELECT  char_length(trim(dse.event_text))
FROM discussion_stream_event dse;`

Comment: @JNevill, that is not the case: `select length('oooo      '::varchar); 10`.

Comment: What is the exact definition of the column type? Have you recently upgraded the database or the OS it runs on?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 


Column name = event_text
Data type = nvarchar(333)
Identity? = false
Nullable? = true

Description = Text specific to this event - not the stream text directly, but the dynamic text to substitute into an event-appropriate message when rendering the stream.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You are right. Strike my comment on right-padded spaces in varchar(). That is a likelyhood in this scenario.

Comment: `nvarchar` is not a Postgres type, are you sure you are looking at the correct database?

Comment: After reading my last post I realized the table I am using contains truncated text content.  I can connect to another table and pull the full text from there.

Thank you everyone!